# Will using same Google account hurt my new site if one site under my account is penalized?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing

Is there any problem for using same Google account if one of my site is penalized by Google? How carefully will my new site get looked over by Google. Would it be rigorous and the review of my new site very strict?

Comment: If it is at mass level then you should think about it, otherwise everybody make mistake.

Comment: @Goyllo, what do you mean by mass level?

Comment: Google looks at site(s), not accounts. Penalties only pass from one site to the next if they are directly involved with the misdemeanour. So, it doesn't matter if you have 10 accounts or 1 with 10 sites.

Comment: @Goyllo, So you are saying google will review the second site more strictly than the first site

Comment: @Simon, i asked this because i am an individual and not planning to take bad chance.

Comment: I am not planning for 10 accounts or 1 with 10 sites. I only want to make sure no mistake comes against my new site

Comment: Doesn't matter if your a company or a individual. Google does not penalise for having multiple sites on Google Search Console, even when one of those have been penalize it does not impact the other sites in anyway, why would it? Google scores websites, not accounts. You often have companies and website designers like myself have 100's of properties added in the search console, imagine what would happen for the likes of one site impacted all the others, you would have legit websites being penalized for another website's wrong doing, that would be bonkers!!

Comment: In other words... Google Search Console has no influence in search rankings or penalties, only that you can manually submit a appear against a penalty, the rest is left to crawlers and their alorythim, again nothing to do with the Search Console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62433/discussion-between-david-john-and-simon-hayter).